# Why does division return zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, integer-division

Here is the code I'm using in the example:

```
 PRINT @set1
 PRINT @set2

 SET @weight= @set1 / @set2;
 PRINT @weight
```

Here is the result:

```
47
638
0
```

I would like to know why it's returning `0` instead of `0,073667712`

Comment: it's is an 'int':
DECLARE @weight INT

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Either declare set1 and set2 as floats instead of integers or cast them to floats as part of the calculation:

```
SET @weight= CAST(@set1 AS float) / CAST(@set2 AS float);
```

Answer (score 37):

When you use only integers in a division, you will get integer division. When you use (at least one) double or float, you will get floating point division (and the answer you want to get).

So you can

1. declare one or both of the variables as float/double
2. cast one or both of the variables to float/double.

Do not just cast the result of the integer division to double: the division was already performed as integer division, so the numbers behind the decimal are already lost.

Comment: +1 because I think you explained it a little better and mentioned that only one of the values needs to be a float/double

Answer (score 14):

Simply mutiply the bottom of the division by 1.0 (or as many decimal places as you want)

```
PRINT @set1 
PRINT @set2 
SET @weight= @set1 / @set2 *1.00000; 
PRINT @weight
```

Comment: Thanks man. Your code helped me to answer this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532187/how-to-calculate-percent-of-total-within-group-by-statement  Can you tell me how to truncate the extra zeros caused by that multiplication ? Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Because it's an integer. You need to declare them as floating point numbers or decimals, or cast to such in the calculation.

Comment: If I change the @weight variable to float, is it enough ?

Answer (score 2):

if you declare it as float or any decimal format it will display

> 0

only

E.g :

```
declare @weight float;

SET @weight= 47 / 638; PRINT @weight
```

Output : 0

If you want the output as

> 0.073667712

E.g

```
declare @weight float;

SET @weight= 47.000000000 / 638.000000000; PRINT @weight
```

Comment: Hum ok I get it now but the two numbers I want to divide are variables , and it doesn't seems to work if the .0000 isn't specified in the variable.

Comment: so you need to cast both @set1 and @set2 to float :)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server direct division of two integer returns integer even if the result should be the float.  There is an example below to get it across:

```
--1--
declare @weird_number_float float
set @weird_number_float=22/7
select @weird_number_float

--2--
declare @weird_number_decimal decimal(18,10)
set @weird_number_decimal=22/7 
select @weird_number_decimal

--3--
declare @weird_number_numeric numeric
set @weird_number_numeric=22/7 
select @weird_number_numeric

--Right way

declare @weird_number float
set @weird_number=cast(22 as float)/cast(7 as float)
select @weird_number
```

Just last block will return the 3,14285714285714.  In spite of the second block defined with right precision the result will be 3.00000.

Answer (score -1):

```
 CAST(@set1 AS float)
 CAST(@set2 AS float)
```

or

```
convert(float,@set1)
convert(float,@set2)
```

First convert into float then apply operator