# how to calculate percent of total within group by statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 1 record per sale per salesperson per day

```
NAME  DATE
joe   1-1-13
joe   1-1-13
joe   1-1-13
dave  1-1-13
joe   1-2-13
```

I used this to create & populate the table

```
create table #sales (name varchar(10), salesdate date )
insert into #sales (name, salesdate) 
values ('joe', '01-01-2013'), ('joe','01-01-2013'), 
       ('joe', '01-01-2013'), ('dave','01-01-2013'),  
         ('joe','01-02-2013')
```

I want a query to pull up the percent of each salesperson's sales by day

(for example  on 1-1-13 Joe sold 3 units out of 4 total for the day (75%) 
but I dont know how the SQL can pull up the daily total of all sales for the day regardless of salesperson

This is as close as I got.

```
select name, salesdate, count(*) as "dailyTotal"
from #sales
group by name, salesdate
```

How can I include the daily total that is so that it can be used in calculating percent total for the day?

Comment: Wait, I am close to a solution.

Answer (score 11):

Not the most elegant way to do it, but you can try this -

```
select [name],[salesdate], COUNT(*) as dayTotal, 
SUM(COUNT(*)) over() as AllSales, 
(COUNT(*) * 1.0) / SUM(COUNT(*)) over() as dayPercent
FROM [dbo].[sales]
group by [name], [salesdate]
```

I removed the # in your table name. Btw, this code depends on OVER() clause. You can find out how to truncate the excess zeros yourself.

```
name    salesdate   dayTotal    AllSales    dayPercent
dave    2013-01-01  1           5           0.200000000000
joe   2013-01-01    3           5           0.600000000000
joe   2013-01-02    1           5           0.200000000000
```

HTH.

If that query looks too complicated to you, then look at this one first. It will give you an idea of what I am trying to do.

```
select [name],[salesdate], COUNT(*) as dayTotal, 
SUM(COUNT(*)) over() as AllSales
FROM [dbo].[sales]
group by [name], [salesdate]
```

Comment: Good answer, but why did you remove the # symbol?

Comment: very good answer, I didnt know you could use sum with a blank over() clause

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker - The table did not appear in studio when I used a #. So, I removed it. Maybe I did not notice it.

Comment: @user2323932 - did it help ? How did you modify the code to alter the decimal part ?

Comment: Trojan, the single hash indicates a temporary table, one that is only visible to the session that created it and that is automatically dropped when the session disconnects. They are created in the tempdb database. Also, here's another "good answer" - I didn't know about a blank OVER clause either.

Answer (score 7):

The most upvoted answer doesn't seem correct.

The OP has the expected answer

> for example on 1-1-13 Joe sold 3 units out of 4 total for the day (75%)

and yet the upvoted answer shows 60%.

Instead of summing over all data it should be partitioned by day, here's a better example:

```
select [name],[salesdate], COUNT(*) as dayTotal, 
SUM(COUNT(*)) over(PARTITION BY salesdate) as AllDaySales, 
(COUNT(*) * 1.0) / SUM(COUNT(*)) over(PARTITION BY salesdate) as dayPercent
FROM [dbo].[sales]
group by [name], [salesdate]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a nested query to get the daily total:

```
BEGIN

    create table #sales (name varchar(10), salesdate date )

    insert into #sales (name, salesdate) values 
        ('joe', '01-01-2013'), 
        ('joe', '01-01-2013'), 
        ('joe', '01-01-2013'), 
        ('dave', '01-01-2013'),  
        ('joe', '01-02-2013'),
        ('dave', '01-02-2013')

    SELECT name, salesdate, COUNT(*) AS personDailyTotal, MAX(dailyTotal) AS dailyTotal, 
        (COUNT(*) * 100.0) / MAX(dailyTotal) AS [Percent]
    FROM #sales
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT salesdate as [day], COUNT(*) as dailyTotal 
        FROM #sales 
        GROUP BY salesdate
    ) AS [Total] ON salesdate = [day]
    GROUP BY name, salesdate

END
```

Comment: Errors - Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Percent'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

Comment: Okay, bad choice of field name - just put it square brackets

Comment: There you go, added the whole script so you can see it working. Don't forget to drop the table at the end of the script as you can't paste code with a command to drop the table in it

Comment: I had to tweak this a little to work with some messy data, but this worked excellently.

Answer (score 0):

-- Use Below Query

```
select T1.salesdate, name ,convert(numeric(18,2),convert(decimal,count(*)) * 100 / T2.total) as percentage from #sales T1
     inner join (
     select salesdate,count(*) as total from #sales group by salesdate
     ) as T2
     on T1.salesdate = T2.salesdate
     group by name,T1.salesdate,T2.total
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.