# How can i group similar values from a select statement, and then take the percentage for each similar result

Tags: mysql, sql, select

my task is the following: I have this select statement:

```
select
pav_idn_avaliacao avaliacao, 
pav_idn_pergunta pergunta_id, 
per_des_descricao descriao_pergunta,
if(per_idn_resposta = 2, (select ope_des_descricao from slt_opcoes_pergunta where ope_idn_pergunta = per_idn_pergunta AND ope_des_valor = pav_des_valor),pav_des_valor) resposta 
from 
slt_pergunta_avaliacao, 
slt_pergunta 
where 
per_idn_pergunta = pav_idn_pergunta 
AND pav_idn_pergunta IN (393,394,395,3956,397,398,399,400,401,402,403,404,405)
```

It brings me like the following results:

```
avaliacao pergunta_id descricao_         pergunta_resposta
16        401         question 1:        2
16        401         question 1:        3
16        401         question 1:        2
16        401         question 1:        3
16        401         question 1:        4
```

What i have to do is: join and count the similar "pergunta_reposta" for each pergunta id, then i need to have an percentage for each "pergunta_resposta". The desired results would be like the flollowing:

```
avaliacao pergunta_id descricao_         pergunta_resposta count_pergunta_resposta percentage
16        401         question 1:        2                 2                       40
16        401         question 1:        3                 2                       40
16        401         question 1:        4                 1                       20
```

There's a way in MySQL i can achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: What constitutes "simliar" in this situation?

Comment: Hi @DanBracuk, i mean a row with same values: 
`16        401         question 1:        2`
`16        401         question 1:        2`

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to calculate percent of total within group by statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532187/how-to-calculate-percent-of-total-within-group-by-statement)