# Using COUNT and Return Percentage Against SUM of Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Pretty simple question I suppose, but I can't find the answer on here!

I am trying to calculate the volume of records based on a WHERE clause, as well as return a percentage of those records based on the same where clause. The percentage would be calculated against the total amount of records in the database. For example, I count all my records that meet "MyCondition":

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [MyTable]     
WHERE Condition='MyCondition'
```

This works fine. However, how does one take that count, and return the percentage it equates to when put against all the records in the database? In other words, I want to see the percentage of how many records meet WHERE Condition='MyCondition' in regards to the total record count.

Sorry for the simple question and TIA! I am using MS SQL 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do simply divide the match of the count by the total number of records.

**Sample Data:**

```
create table test (MatchColumn int)

insert into test (MatchColumn)
values (1),(1),(1),(2),(3),(4)
```

**Match Condition:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) MatchValues, 
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test) TotalRecords,
      CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT)/CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test) AS FLOAT)*100 Percentage
FROM [test]     
WHERE MatchColumn=1
```

**Returns:**

```
| MATCHVALUES | TOTALRECORDS | PERCENTAGE |
|-------------|--------------|------------|
|           3 |            6 |         50 |
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67425/23)

**Using a CTE:**

Another option is to do the same with a **[CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)** and reference the columns it creates:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) MatchValues, 
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test) TotalRecords      
   FROM [test]     
   WHERE MatchColumn=1)
SELECT MatchValues, TotalRecords, 
       CAST(MatchValues AS FLOAT)/CAST(TotalRecords AS FLOAT)*100 Percentage
FROM CTE
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67425/25)

**NOTE:** Casting the counts to a `float` to calculate a percentage is required as dividing 2 `int` values would return an `int`, but in this case we want a decimal value less than 0, which would simply be 0 if it were an `int`.

**Reference:**

### [SQL Server, division returns zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666407/sql-server-division-returns-zero)

Comment: you are ballin out of control sir.

Comment: Why thanks, have posted an alternative that achieves the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another method that only hits the base table once.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalCount
    ,SUM(case when Condition = 'MyCondition' then 1 else 0 end) as ConditionalCount
FROM [MyTable]
```

Comment: But how to return the conditional Count as a percentage I see the TotalCount returning all rows, and I see the ConditionalCount returning the WHEREed clause rows, but I need the amount that meet the where clause, and the percentage it equates to versus the sum of all records.

Comment: Do you also need the individual counts? If no, then just do the math inline. If you do need them then you could move the above to a cte. It isn't clear what you want for output.

Comment: Ideally, the ConditionalCount (that which meets the where clause) as a integer. Secondly, the percentage of the ConditionalCount versus the Sum of all records.

Comment: So just adjust the above query a little bit to suit. hint...you just need to add the sum above as the divisor.

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this.

```
create table test (MatchColumn int)
insert into test (MatchColumn)
values (1),(1),(1),(2),(3),(4)

SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE MatchColumn=1) MatchValues, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test) TotalRecords,
((SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) FROM test WHERE MatchColumn=1)/CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test) AS FLOAT)*100) Percentage
```