# sql 2014 problems storing decimal

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

i have a stored procedure and i initially create a temp table.  i populate the first 3 columns and then i want to get the percentage when jobs are voided.  but i can't seem to get a good value.  if Void=10 and Total_Jobs=59 then 10/59 = 0.16 but it populates table with zero.  what am i doing wrong?

```
Create table #tbl_WeeklyJobsRpt
(
Region_Code varchar(25),
Void int DEFAULT 0,
Total_Jobs int DEFAULT 0,
Void_Pctg decimal(10,2) DEFAULT 0
)

-- Void_Pctg
Update #tbl_WeeklyJobsRpt
  set Void_Pctg = ((Void)/Total_Jobs)
Where Void <> 0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server, division returns zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666407/sql-server-division-returns-zero)

Answer (score 1):

Both values are int so the result is `int` too and the value is being rounded down. 
Try `1.0*Void/Total_Jobs` - 1.0 causes implicit cast.

Answer (score 0):

@Alex, that was the correct answer, thank you.
I had to set my fields as float and then when i divided later on, it all worked.  I thought I had tried that already but obviously i missed a detail somewhere.
[Answer here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666407/sql-server-division-returns-zero)