# Calculating percentage SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, count

I am trying to run an SQL query that, for each month, calculates the average time taken for engineering to complete a project and the percentage of on-time projects.

```
SELECT
    AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, [DateBlockReleased], [DateEngineeringTargetComplete])),
    SUM(IIF(DATEDIFF(DAY, [DateBlockReleased], [DateEngineeringTargetComplete]) >= 0, 1, 0)) AS [OnTime]
FROM
    [JobData].[JobData],
    [JobData].[BOMInfo],
    [JobData].[DesignInfo]
WHERE ...
```

This currently returns the average time taken and the number of on time projects, however, I'm not sure how to divide this by the number of total projects. I've tried adding /COUNT(*) * 100 after the sum but this always returns 0.

Comment: I see multiple tables in the `FROM`, but no `JOIN`.  Something isn't right.  Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to calcualte.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server, division returns zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1666407/2029983)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute the ratio of on-time projects, you could use `avg()`:

```
AVG(CASE 
    WHEN DateEngineeringTargetComplete >= DateBlockReleased
    THEN 1.0 
    ELSE 0.0 
END) AS OnTimeRatio
```

If you want the value on a 0-100 scale, just multiply the ratio by 100.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to multiply with 1.0

```
if you are doing select a/b, do it like select a*1.0/b
```

In your example do:  `/COUNT(*) * 100.0`