# Transformation of units in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset, df, that has a column of values that are in MB. I would like to transform into TB.

```
MB

10000000
20000000
```

Desired

```
TB

9.09
18.18
```

Doing

```
select MB AS 'TB', (CONVERT([int],round([MB]/((1024)*(1024)),(0)))) AS TB from df
```

However, the result I get is

```
MB

0
0
```

I am still researching. Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server, division returns zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666407/sql-server-division-returns-zero)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/` is integer division in SQL Server.
It means, that for example

```
SELECT 4 / 5
```

will return 0.

But, if you write

```
SELECT 4 / 5.0
```

you'll get 0.8

`5.0` is treated as `decimal` type and all values in the expression are converted to `decimal` and division is no longer integer.

So, you can use `1024.0` constant in the expression, and all the values in it will be converted to `decimal` type and division will not be integer.

In the question you say that you want to show results with two decimal places, so you should not convert result to `int`.

```
select 
    [MB]
    ,round([MB]/(1024.0*1024.0), 2) AS TB 
from df
```