# Add values of 2 calculated fields in a view to make a 3rd calculated column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a view for our Mobile Device Management system that collects cellular data usage in Bytes. I have a CONVERT function that convers the Download and Upload from Bytes to GB as 2 extra columns. There's no total column and I don't need the total in Bytes, but what I do need is the Total in GB. So I'm trying to add together the contents of the calculated "Download (GB)" and "Upload (GB)" for each row.

The View's SQL code is as follows (I've formatted it to make it look hopefully a bit more readable)

```
SELECT
dbo.DevInfo.DevId,
dbo.DevInfo.DevName,
dbo.AndroidWorkProduct.Title,
dbo.DeviceStatNetTraffic.Application,
dbo.DeviceStatNetTraffic.TimeStamp,
dbo.DeviceStatNetTraffic.Upload,
dbo.DeviceStatNetTraffic.Download,
dbo.DevInfo.LastCheckInTime,
dbo.Person.LoginName,
dbo.Person.FirstName,
dbo.Person.MiddleName,
dbo.Person.LastName,
dbo.DeviceGroup.Name,
dbo.DevInfo.Model,
dbo.DevInfo.Manufacturer,
dbo.DevInfo.OSVersion,
dbo.DevInfo.PhoneNumber,
dbo.Person.CustomProperty1,
dbo.Person.CustomProperty2,
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), dbo.DeviceStatNetTraffic.Upload / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) AS [Upload (GB)],
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), dbo.DeviceStatNetTraffic.Download / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) AS [Download (GB)]
FROM           
dbo.DeviceStatNetTraffic
WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN dbo.DevInfo WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.DeviceStatNetTraffic.DeviceId = dbo.DevInfo.DeviceId
INNER JOIN dbo.Person ON dbo.DevInfo.CurrentPersonId = dbo.Person.PersonId
INNER JOIN dbo.DeviceGroupDevice ON dbo.DevInfo.DeviceId = dbo.DeviceGroupDevice.DeviceId
INNER JOIN dbo.DeviceGroup ON dbo.DeviceGroupDevice.DeviceGroupId = dbo.DeviceGroup.DeviceGroupId
INNER JOIN dbo.AndroidWorkProduct ON dbo.DeviceStatNetTraffic.Application = dbo.AndroidWorkProduct.AndroidProductId
```

The lines performing the conversion are:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), dbo.DeviceStatNetTraffic.Upload / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) AS [Upload (GB)],
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), dbo.DeviceStatNetTraffic.Download / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) AS [Download (GB)]
```

I've tried things like:

```
SUM('Upload (GB)' + 'Download (GB)') AS [Total (GB)]

SUM(dbo.custom_datausage.'Upload (GB)' + dbo.custom_datausage.'Download (GB)') AS [Total (GB)]
```

But neither work. I've done some investigation on summing or adding together 2 calculated fields but I couldn't really understand it as SQL isn't my area of expertise or my day job. Also the examples looked more tailored to queries being run rather than views that other systems will pull from.

Any help in being able to get a Upload (GB), Download (GB) and Total (GB) set of columns would be much appreciated.

Here is an example of the current output with any PII (person information) removed:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+-------------------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+
|                       Title                        |         Application          |        TimeStamp        |   Upload   |  Download  |     LastCheckInTime     |   Model   | Manufacturer | OSVersion | Upload (GB) | Download (GB) |
+----------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+-------------------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+
| Microsoft SharePoint                               | com.microsoft.sharepoint     | 2020-11-09 12:00:35.263 |   28942282 | 2926094789 | 2021-04-22 09:48:05.000 | SM-T515   | samsung      |        10 | 0.00        | 2.00          |
| Microsoft SharePoint                               | com.microsoft.sharepoint     | 2020-11-06 14:00:01.137 |   16001723 | 2494834025 | 2021-04-22 09:50:03.000 | SM-T515   | samsung      |        10 | 0.00        | 2.00          |
| Google Chrome: Fast & Secure                       | com.android.chrome           | 2020-11-20 18:00:00.777 |    7337215 | 2725987798 | 2021-04-22 03:47:28.000 | SM-A515U  | samsung      |        10 | 0.00        | 2.00          |
| Google Chrome: Fast & Secure                       | com.android.chrome           | 2020-12-15 18:00:59.257 |  529663816 | 2652521085 | 2021-04-22 09:49:36.000 | SM-A715F  | samsung      |        10 | 0.00        | 2.00          |
| Microsoft Outlook: Secure email, calendars & files | com.microsoft.office.outlook | 2021-02-10 22:00:19.053 |  524582841 | 3007983510 | 2021-04-22 09:34:35.000 | SM-J330FN | samsung      |         9 | 0.00        | 2.00          |
| ZOOM Cloud Meetings                                | us.zoom.videomeetings        | 2021-02-15 12:00:41.577 | 1438142679 | 2300425438 | 2021-04-22 09:46:07.000 | SM-A705FN | samsung      |        10 | 1.00        | 2.00          |
| Google Chrome: Fast & Secure                       | com.android.chrome           | 2021-02-15 12:00:41.597 |  131430179 | 2110910408 | 2021-04-22 09:46:07.000 | SM-A705FN | samsung      |        10 | 0.00        | 1.00          |
| Google Chrome: Fast & Secure                       | com.android.chrome           | 2020-11-17 18:00:01.670 |   16605803 | 2496396859 | 2021-04-22 09:50:25.000 | SM-A515U  | samsung      |        10 | 0.00        | 2.00          |
+----------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------+------------+------------+-------------------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Comment: FYI, [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. Stick to aliasing your objects and using those to qualify your columns. It'll make your sQL far much succinct. *Good* use of White space would also not go amiss for reabability; all left aligned code is can be very difficult to read.

Comment: First of all, using `SUM` most likely implies that you want to do a `GROUP BY` query.  Can you also include a minimal version of the query you want to do?  Your problem is that you defined the computed columns in the same select where you also want to reuse those aliases.  You can't do that.

Comment: `But neither work` What exactly do you mean by this ? You get syntax error ? The result is not as expected ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server, division returns zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666407/sql-server-division-returns-zero)

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to decimal your field, and then divide by 1024 3 times

```
declare @bytes int = 131430179 

select convert(decimal, @bytes)/1024/1024/1024 as GB
```

You are converting the data after dividing the integer field, so you are loosing the precision.

Output:

```
0.1224038926877929 GB
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does integer division, so `1 / 2` is `0` rather than `0.5`.  Converting the *result* to a decimal doesn't fix this.

The simplest method to fix this is to throw in a decimal point:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), dbo.DeviceStatNetTraffic.Upload / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / 1024.0) AS [Upload (GB)],
```

Note that you should learn to use table aliases, so your query is easier to read:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), dst.Upload / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / 1024.0) AS [Upload (GB)],
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a Total Column (Upload+Download) for each row you need to sum that values by column they are coming, not by the aliases that you have declared.

When you use the SUM() you need use a `GROUP BY` clause, because this will sum the values of all rows (doesn't make much sense because you can sum this values out of query).

Try to sum the two values in bytes so you convert to Gb:

If you want to create a Total Column (Upload+Download) for each row you need to sum that values by column they are coming, not by the aliases that you have declared.

When you use the SUM() you need use a `GROUP BY` clause, because this will sum the values of all rows (doesn't make much sense because you can sum this values out of query).

Try to sum the two values in bytes so you convert to Gb:

```
SELECT
    dbo.DevInfo.DevId,
    dbo.DevInfo.DevName,
    dbo.AndroidWorkProduct.Title,
    dbo.DeviceStatNetTraffic.Application,
    dbo.DeviceStatNetTraffic.TimeStamp,
    dbo.DeviceStatNetTraffic.Upload,
    dbo.DeviceStatNetTraffic.Download,
    dbo.DevInfo.LastCheckInTime,
    dbo.Person.LoginName,
    dbo.Person.FirstName,
    dbo.Person.MiddleName,
    dbo.Person.LastName,
    dbo.DeviceGroup.Name,
    dbo.DevInfo.Model,
    dbo.DevInfo.Manufacturer,
    dbo.DevInfo.OSVersion,
    dbo.DevInfo.PhoneNumber,
    dbo.Person.CustomProperty1,
    dbo.Person.CustomProperty2,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), dbo.DeviceStatNetTraffic.Upload / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) AS [Upload (GB)],
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), dbo.DeviceStatNetTraffic.Download / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) AS [Download (GB)],
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), (dbo.DeviceStatNetTraffic.Upload + dbo.DeviceStatNetTraffic.Download) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) AS [Total (Gb)]
FROM           
    dbo.DeviceStatNetTraffic WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.DevInfo WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.DeviceStatNetTraffic.DeviceId = dbo.DevInfo.DeviceId
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Person ON dbo.DevInfo.CurrentPersonId = dbo.Person.PersonId
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.DeviceGroupDevice ON dbo.DevInfo.DeviceId = dbo.DeviceGroupDevice.DeviceId
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.DeviceGroup ON dbo.DeviceGroupDevice.DeviceGroupId = dbo.DeviceGroup.DeviceGroupId
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.AndroidWorkProduct ON dbo.DeviceStatNetTraffic.Application = dbo.AndroidWorkProduct.AndroidProductId
```