# SQL Server Maths functions different between Declared Variables/Actual Values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, math

I've been trying to create something in SQL Server for reporting purposes, and the figures simply haven't worked... I originally done the calculations in Microsoft excel and got the formula i wanted to translate to SQL Server and worked through it, and got a value i wasn't expecting. So I've broken it down to the very basics; From what I understand, the 2 Queries below are exactly the same. However SQL is calculating them differently. Please see below code which is causing the problem.

```
DECLARE @CostPrice AS NUMERIC (5,3)
DECLARE @MarginPercent AS NUMERIC (5,3)

SET @UnitPrice = 1.90
SET @CostPrice = 1.25
SET @MarginPercent = 50

SELECT @CostPrice/(1-(@MarginPercent/100)) (Returns value of 2.5, which I want)
SELECT 1.25/(1-(50/100)) (Returns value of 1.25, which is not what i expected)
```

Comment: Hint: [implicit data type conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15). If you execute `SELECT 1.25/(1-(50/100.0))` you'll find the difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server, division returns zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666407/sql-server-division-returns-zero)

Answer (score 0):

Zhorov:
Hint: `implicit data type conversion`. `If you execute SELECT 1.25/(1-(50/100.0))` you'll find the difference. –

I've took this advice and adjusted my code accordingly now resolved and works!

Many Thanks

Andy