# Column in SSRS to show value according to the parameter value in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have one column in SSRS report which should show the value according to the parameter, if the parameter is selected to Million Euro then it should show the value in Million Euro which means the value should be divided by 10^6,if the parameter is selected as K Euro then the value should be as K Euros which means the value should be divided by 10^3.
I tried to create a dataset where I wrote the SQL query and made a parameter but it didn't worked.
Can anyone give the solution like what should be my dataset query and how should I map it with the parameter.
I used

```
if @CurrencyConv='MEuro' BEGIN 
select 1/Power(10,6) as ProductValue
end
else BEGIN select 1/Power(10,3) as ProductValue
END
```

And made a parameter where I hardcoded the available values as 'MEuro' and 'KEuro'
And in that column's expression I multiplied the column value with Dataset Value(ProductValue)
Column name is Converted Booking and I have to multiply that column according to the parameter value so if the value is MEuro then it should be `[Converted Booking]*1/Power(10,6)`
In Sql the below query is working

```
select [Converted Booking]*1/Power(10,6) from T_GCP_REP
```

How to apply same thing in SSRS

Comment: What was your attempt then? Show us in the question using the [edit] feature. Sounds like you just need a `CASE` expression.

Comment: That is going to always return `0` due to all the values being an `int`.

Comment: okk So what should I do then??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server, division returns zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666407/sql-server-division-returns-zero)

Comment: No it didn't because for me in SQL it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the final calculated value in you dataset then change your dataset query to

```
SELECT 
    *,
    CAST([Converted Booking] as float) / CASE WHEN @CurrencyConv = 'MEuro' THEN 1000000 ELSE 1000 END as ConvertedBookingFinal
    from T_GCP_REP
```

**OR**

If you want to do this purely in SSRS (maybe you cannot change your dataset query?)
The Set the parameter **values** to 1000 and 1000000 respectively.

Then in the report textbox set the expression to

```
= Fields.Converted_Booking.Value / Parameters!myParameterName.Value
```

you can leave the parameter labels as "MEuro" etc you only need to change the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the field in your SQL, you can add it using a CASE statement.

```
SELECT *, 1/Power(10, CASE WHEN @CurrencyConv = 'MEuro' THEN 6 ELSE 3 END) as ProductValue
FROM TABLE
```

or you could use the new IIF in SQL like SSRS has

```
SELECT *, 1/Power(10, IIF(@CurrencyConv = 'MEuro', 6, 3)) as ProductValue
FROM TABLE
```

For an SSRS expression, an IIF statement could also be used:

```
=1/Power(10, IIF(Parameters!CurrencyConv.Value = 'MEuro', 6, 3))
```

Though it might be better to use MEuro as the parameter label and have 6 as the value (with KEuro, 3 for the other possible value). Then you could shorten it to:

```
=1/Power(10, Parameters!CurrencyConv.Value)
```

Comment: Yes in Sql it is working.
But how to apply same thing in SSRS