# Why a division of integers result as integer in T-SQL instead of float

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Why `SELECT 1/5` result is `0` instead of `0.2` in SQL server Transact SQL?

IF i use `SELECT 1.0/5` result is  `0.200000`

Comment: Why would it result in anything else...? If I have 2 `varchar` values and concatenate them, should I get an `nvarchar`? No. If you have 2 `int` data types and do *something* with them, you get an `int` back.

Comment: It is documented to work that way. What more could you want?

Comment: A `float`, however, would be an *awful* choice of a data type to get back as well if you were doing division with `int` values. You'd be inputting base 10 values and getting back a base 2; that would result in all sorts of rounding issues. At worst you could "expect" a `decimal`/`numeric` but that's still wrong; an application shouldn't be implicitly converting data types just because you're doing a specific type of arithmetic.

Comment: This behavior is actually the standard for all languages I know of.

Comment: Of further related interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719044/how-to-get-a-float-result-by-dividing-two-integer-values-using-t-sql and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server, division returns zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666407/sql-server-division-returns-zero)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would expect anything else here. If you have 2 values of the **same** data type and do *something* (that isn't explicitly or implicitly casting the data type) with them why would you expect to get a different data type back? This is standard behaviour across *every* language, not just T-SQL or even SQL as a whole.

As I mentioned in the comment, if you had 2 `varchar` values and concatenated them, you wouldn't expect to get an `nvarchar` or perhaps a `char` back; you'd expect to get a `varchar` back. If you subtracted a `datetime` from a `datetime` (which as much as I hate, you *can* do) you wouldn't expect a `time` or perhaps a `int` value back.

Just because you're doing division doesn't change that; by providing `int` values you are, by definition, stating you want a `int` value back.

For the latter statement, `SELECT 1.0/5`, you have 2 different data types, a `decimal(2,1)` and an `int` respectively. When dealing with data of differing types one of the data types has to be implicitly converted to the data type of the other; which is determined by [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). `decimal` has a higher precedence that `int`, so that `int` is converted first, and then the division completed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in many programming languages  the aritmetic processor  cast 2 integer division as float or real type that why i didnt catch this glinch of TSQL, afterwards is SQL.

Comment: It's not a glitch at all. If you are using a language that does that, ***THAT*** is the glitched language, @ontananza .