# SQL arithmetic does not return same answer when I multiply

Tags: sql

I'm doing a free course on DataCamp and I am at the aggregating function section.
It is asking me to get the percentage of people who are no longer alive.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(deathdate) * 100.0 / COUNT(*)
FROM people
```

Returns 9.37

```
SELECT
  COUNT(deathdate) / COUNT(*) * 100.0
FROM people
```

Returns 0.0

The right answer is the first code, but why doesn't the second code return the same as the first? Why can't I multiply by 100.0 after I divide?

Comment: Hint: order of operations and integer division. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666407/sql-server-division-returns-zero

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, `COUNT(deathdate) * 100.0` is performed first and since it includes a number with a decimal, the result is a double-precision/float value. Then the divide by `COUNT(*)` can give you a result with decimal places.

In the second example, `COUNT(deathdate) / COUNT(*)` uses two integer values which causes the fraction to be lost resulting in zero. Then, zero * 100.0 is zero.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I undestand.